# TFS 2012 Team Build and Web Application Deployment - ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msdeploy, tfsbuild

We have a solution consisting of several class libraries, and a Web
Application Project.  We are using TFS 2012 with Team Build.  The solution
compiles correctly on the build server.

I am currently trying to do this via MSBuild Arguments.

/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False  /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=`https://testWebServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=direct` /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:DeployIisAppPath="direct"
/p:AuthType=NTLM

The solution builds but does not deploy.  I get the following error message:

> msdeploy error ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID: Web deployment task failed.
>   ( Could not connect to the remote computer ("https"). Make sure that
>   the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect
>   to that computer.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID.)
>   [C:\Builds\1\ProjectName\Solution General Build\Sources\Temp
>   Source\ProjectName\Solution\Project.csproj]

Is there another argument I should be passing to specify the server?  I did
not intend for https to be the server name...  I have tried omitting the
https:// to no avail, error is the same, so it is getting the value from
somewhere.

I have tried this with the following values for MsDeployServiceUrl:

- `https://testWebServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=direct`
- `https://testWebServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd`
- `"https://testWebServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=direct"`
- `https://192.168.X.X:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=direct`
- `"https://192.168.X.X:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=direct"`
- `testWebServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=direct`

## Update

Alright, the following is at least connecting:

- /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=`testWebServer`

I have seen numerous posts concerning that particular argument, and almost invariably they are a URL, not just a hostname (the ones that appear to be a hostname I thought were just written that way for brevity).

I am now, however, faced with a new problem.  I have made the Build Service Account (domain account) local admin on the webserver, and I am getting `msdeploy error ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN` as well as an Audit failure in the Security log.

## Resolution

These are the MSBuild arguments I am currently going with.
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc /p:MsDeployServiceUrl="https://SERVER:8172/MsDeploy.axd" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployIisAppPath="siteName"

I am now getting ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.  Apparently I have either not set up the delegation correctly or the IIS Manager User I have created is somehow incorrect.  Regardless that will go in a different post if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried puting the url inside double quotes ? Seems that it gets cut of at : !

Comment: Indeed I have. I updated my post with some values I have tried.  I am sure there are others I have attempted but I can't remember...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the Server and IIS version, you are using? 
IIS 6 uses **Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc)**, whereas IIS 7 usually uses **Web Management Service (WMSvc)** which have different URLs (besides, you have to be an admin on the target server to execute MsDepSvc.

Can you try specifying

```
/P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
```

Based on [this article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_24.html) from Troy Hunt, **Web Management Service (WMSvc)** is using

```
.axd
```

URLs (the one you specify), whereas you are trying to force it use **RemoteAgent** publish method which seems to be inconsistent.

See [this article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_24.html) for complete set of differencies between `WMSvc` and `RemoteAgent` publish methods.

Comment: In this case, most likely, you need /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc (which is default for IIS7). I suggest that you first try to connect using console msdeploy client to ensure you have target server's msdeploy services are Up and Running.

Comment: Would you be available to chat for a few minutes?  I can create a chat room instead of filling up this area with back and forth...

Comment: Commandline returns the error Destination Not Reachable.  I have verified that the service is running (net start wmsvc) and I have disabled the firewalls completely on both machines to see if I can get it to work.  No dice.

Comment: Re-installed web deploy tool after running the commands in this post `http://forums.iis.net/post/1960329.aspx`.  Now I am connecting, but am unauthorized.  I will go ahead and close this post as I have made headway past my previous problems.  If I am still stuck with unauthorized errors, I may create a new post.

Comment: >> Would you be available to chat for a few minutes? I can create a chat room instead of filling up this area with back and forth... Sure, you can contact me in skype ivan.antsipau or just give a link to a chat room of your choice

Comment: Did you finally resolve your "ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED"? I'm running into the same problem as above.  I followed [this](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/11/29/deploy-from-a-team-foundation-server-build-to-web-site-without-specifying-password-in-the-build/) but I am still getting the error. My parameters: /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Dev 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:UserName=”” 
/p:AuthType=NTLM 
/P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. To resolve the issue I tried the following steps:

1. As it was a hosted server we had to make sure that the port 8172 was open (obviously).
2. Creating a new login and set this up in IIS -> Deploy -> Configure -> Configure Web Deploy Publishing on the target server. I made sure that the password didn't have any spaces in to avoid the quotes issue just to be sure.
3. Actually running a manual deployment from the build server.
4. Finally specifying an IP address in the MSDeployServicerl:
   /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/msdeploy.axd

None of the web site names worked for me either. None of my parameters had quotes in. Of course if you leave a space in incorrectly in one of your parameters you will get the error: 
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified